# "No such file or directory" while backing up the SD card using dd on Mac

Tags: backup

The `diskutil` said that my SD card is located on `/dev/disk4`, so I typed

```
sudo dd if=/dev/rdisk4 of=~/Desktop/backup.img bs=1m
```

to backup my SD card. But there is a message

```
dd: ~/Desktop/backup.img: No such file or directory
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Does the ~/Desktop/ directory exist?

Comment: @SteveRobillard It exists. The command works as I change to the target directory and replace it with `sudo dd if=/dev/rdisk4 of=backup.img bs=1m`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are using `sudo` i.e. running with root permission you **DO NOT** have `~` as shortcut for your home directory.

Use **FULL PATHS** or `cd` to the target directory.